# Multiplicative structure on additive group

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring without assumption of existence of unity. Let $R^{\ast} = R \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ as abelian groups. Show how to define multiplication on $R^\ast$ so that it becomes a ring with an ideal that is "ring" isomorphic to $R$.

This is from Martin Isaacs' Algebra, p. 172, #12.4.

Could I define $(r, m) \cdot (s, n)$ in $R \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ as $(mnrs, 1)$? and define the isomorphism between $R \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and $R$ as $(r, m) \mapsto rm$

I should appreciate any help. Thank you.

W.

Comment: $(r,m)(s,n)=(rs+nr+ms,mn)$ has unit $(0,1)$, and $\{(r,0)\}\cong R$

Comment: Thanks, but how would you define the isomorphism map? $(r, m) \mapsto rm$?

Comment: @yoyo defined the isomorphism for you: $(r, 0) \rightarrow r.$

Comment: It seems that all that is left for you to do is verify that $R\oplus\{0\}$ is an ideal in $R^*$.  But this is easy.